# How to append a row of integers into a single list across multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Lets say I have the follow dataframe

```
    col_1    col_2
0    1        2   
1    3        4
```

and I want to create a third column that is a *list of integers*

```
    col_1    col_2    col_3
0     1        2      [1,2]
1     3        4      [3,4]
```

I tried several messy approaches where I convert the values into strings, concatenate them, and the turn it into a list of integers like this:

```
df['col_3'] = df[['col_1', 'col_2']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(x)), axis=1)
```

But it was super messy and super slow and did not return what I was looking for. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: df['col_3'] = list(zip(df.col_1,df.col_2))

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [string.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
   df['col_3'] =  df[['col_1', 'col_2']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat(sep=','),axis=1)
   df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].str.split(',')

  col_1     col_2   col_3
 0    1       2    [1, 2]
 1    3       4     [3, 4]
```

Another option is to use the zip function :

```
df['col_3'] = list(zip(df.col_1,df.col_2))
```

Comment: I think `list(zip(df.col_1,df.col_2))` is faster but the problem is what we do if We have more columns

Comment: hmmm. I would defer to your solutions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

[`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with split.

```
df['col3'] = df.to_dict('split')['data']
```

**Selecting columns**

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].to_dict('split')['data']
```

or with [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
df['col3'] = df[df.columns.difference(['col4'])].to_dict('split')['data']

print(df)
```

We can also use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(list,axis = 1)
#df['col3']=df[['col1','col2']].apply(list,axis = 1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   col_1  col_2    col3
0      1      2  [1, 2]
1      3      4  [3, 4]
```

Comment: but what if I have a `col_4` that I do not want appended to the list in `col_3`?

Comment: if you want only columns 1 and 2yo can select it.please,  check solution I have updated it